# How to quickly analyse large MDB file

Tags: ms-access, size

I need to know how to quickly analyse a large MDB file (about 1GB) to see which tables are causing it to be so big.  Is there something that will easily allow me to show a breakdown of which tables are responsible for how much data.

Comment: Is the app inserting/deleting large datasets? If so, move those inserts/deletes into a temp database that is separate from the real database so there isn't churn in the real data store. If it's being inserted/deleted regularly, it's clearly temporary data and shouldn't be stored in the main data file, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

One of possible scenarios is that mdb file needs to be compacted

You can use vbscript for that, just set correct file paths

```
' For Access 2000, use Application.9
'Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application.9")

' Perform the DB Compact into the new mdb file
' (If there is a problem, then the original mdb is preserved)
objAccess.DbEngine.CompactDatabase strPathToMDB ,strCompactedDB
```

Comment: As well you can use Access application. Tools->Database Utilities->Compact Database